# how to write an API in future async if there is an additional path in it

Tags: api, flutter, async-await

hi guys im beginner in flutter, i want to write API path in my future async connector API, but there is an additional path in it. how to write it? i got an error. below is the code.

```
Future<Map> getData() async {
// final String apiURL = ;
var response = await http.get(
  'https://api.batulimee.com/v1_ship/port_detail?' +
      'port_id=' +
      widget.list[widget.index]['port_id'].toString(),
);
return json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
}

FutureBuilder<Map>(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
            return snapshot.hasData
                ? new Ports(
                    list: snapshot.data['data'],
                  )
                : new Container();
          },
        ),
class Ports extends StatelessWidget {
final List list;
Ports({this.list});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: list.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
    return Card(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Text(
          list[i]['port_website'].toString(),
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
}
}
```

and this is the API path.

```
https://api.batulimee.com/v1_ship/port_detail?port_id=6
```

this is the error.

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 
'List<dynamic>'
```

Comment: Post your error

Comment: sorry im going to edit

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to concatenate Strings in Flutter is using the $ sign.

```
Future<Map> getData() async {
// final String apiURL = ;
var response = await http.get(
  'https://api.batulimee.com/v1_ship/port_detail?port_id=${widget.list[widget.index]['port_id'].toString()}',
);
return json.decode(response.body);
}
```

On an unrelated side note, I would suggest putting the http.get inside a try / catch bloc, or handling any possible errors that could come from the response being null or the response.body being null

Comment: thank you, @baselsader. the script is works, but the error still type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Comment: Your error is telling you where the problem is.

The type you're returning from this function is a Map, however you are dealing with it as a list. 

Please post the code where you call this method (the problem might not be in the method itself, but what you do with the result). Where do you call it? How do you handle the result?

As a suggestion, I would recommend changing the return type to Future<dynamic>, and printing the result (response.body or the json deserialization of it) to see what kind of data you're dealing with, if you don't already know what the response should look like.

Comment: yes, the API has a single data because its 'post'. and i want to display it. thank you for your recommend. Future<dynamic>

Answer (score 0):

In flutter you cannot use string concatenation with variables.

The only way for this is to use dart special character $.
If you want just value from variable than just do this:

```
int a = 1; 
String b = 'Some text $a';
```

If you need value from property of some object than use this way:

```
SomeObject so = new SomeObject();
String v = 'Value from some property of some object is ${so.value}';
```

In your situation solution will be:

```
Future<Map> getData() async {
// final String apiURL = ;
var response = await http.get(
  'https://api.batulimee.com/v1_ship/port_detail?port_id=${widget.list[widget.index]["port_id"].toString()}',
);
return json.decode(response.body);
}
```

Comment: thank you, the script is works, but the error still type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'. i think there is another error in my code. :\

Comment: @Aphron from back end you get data in json and then you need to parse that data in List of object. Take look in this resource https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing